# Условия для скачиваемой информации

Tags: android

Реализую функцию изменения расписания при помощи Parse.com 
Есть Activity, на которой есть около 10 LinearLayout с Textview на каждом layout.
Декларирую TextView перед OnCreate: `TextView TVplace1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);`
Затем ставлю сразу же текст из String, задекларированном чуть выше, в этот TextView (чтобы пользователь с выключенным Интернетом при первом заходе все равно видел какое-то расписание): `TVplace1.setText(place1);`

Затем, В КОНЦЕ onCreate, скачиваю из Parse.com 2 таблицы следующим образом:

```
    public void Parse_download_timetable() {
final TextView TVplace1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
final List<String> list_time_table = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> android_layout_AL = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> list_time_table_NEWDATA = new ArrayList<>();
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("timeTable");
pQuery.orderByAscending("objectId");
    pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (list.size() >= 0) {
                    //пробуем скачать "changes"
                    for (ParseObject po : list) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            Integer c = list.get(i).getInt("change");
                            timetable_reservation_list.add(c);
                            list_time_table.add(po.getObjectId());}

                        //пробуем скачать список "newdata"
                        for (ParseObject po2 : list) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                String c = list.get(i).getString("newData");
                                newdata.add(c);                                   list_time_table_NEWDATA.add(po2.getObjectId());

                                Integer list_time_table_corr = timetable_reservation_list.get(0);
                                if (list_time_table_corr == 1) {
                                    String list_time_table_NEWDATA = newdata.get(0);
                                    final TextView TVplace1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
                                    TVplace1.setText(list_time_table_NEWDATA);
                                } } } }} }} });}
```

Получается, что я скачиваю два списка: "changes" и "newdata". Если в changes стоит 1, то нужно взять из newdata под этим номером новый текст расписания для этого textView.

В конце, после скачивания из Парса таблиц, у меня есть условие для изменения текста при наличии в "changes" 1 следующего вида:

```
Integer list_time_table_corr = timetable_reservation_list.get(0);
                                if (list_time_table_corr == 1) {
                                    String list_time_table_NEWDATA = newdata.get(0);
                                    final TextView TVplace1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
                                    TVplace1.setText(list_time_table_NEWDATA);
                                }
```

Если это условие оставить сразу же в void, который скачивает 2 списка, я получаю дикие глюки в виде тормоза приложения, появляется надпись "Приложение зависло, хотите подождать?", ScroolView этого Activity не движется. 
Я подумал, что стоит создать отдельный void, который, после того, как скачаются данные, и расставит эти изменения.
Сделал я его следующим образом:

```
  `         public void make_changes_timetable(){

    Integer list_time_table_corr = timetable_reservation_list.get(0);
    if (list_time_table_corr == 1) {
        String list_time_table_NEWDATA = newdata.get(0);
        final TextView TVplace1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
        TVplace1.setText(list_time_table_NEWDATA);
    }}
```

`

Такой способ, если вызывать этот void как в onCreate, так и в onResume и в OnStart вызывает ошибку **Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0**

Как я понимаю, эта ошибка означает, что размер таблицы - 0 и невозможно выполнить условие.
Хотя, если оставить это условие в void, который скачивает из Parse.com данные, все работает правильно, только жутко тормозит.

Я подумал, что можно поставить задержку именно для выполнения условий, но ни задержка в 2 секунды, ни в 10 не принесла должного результата - в Активити просто нельзя было зайти.

Вопрос: *Как сделать так, чтобы при заходе пользователь видел расписание, занесенное в String, а после скачивания из Парса и расстановке условий, телефон не тормозил? Следует ли разнести скачивание из Парса таблиц и расстановку по условиям на 2 разных public void? 
Или следует применить другой способ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос.
Я думаю, что вам просто нужно в onCreate заполнить расписание согласно того, как вы это делаете, а работу с парсом вынести в AsyncTask, после выполнения которого заполнить уже новыми данными ваше расписание. 
P.S. Рад, что у Вас все получилось